# Offset cursor is not working when using GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I tried to use offset cursor with GQL (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference) as it is mentioned in the doc that it is supported, however, when it comes to this scenario, it seems the pagination stops working.

Steps to reproduce

1. run `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE feedId = @feedId ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 10` and get the last item as `cursor`
2. run `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE feedId = @feedId ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 10 offset @cursor` will return the exact result from step 1

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue is that Google cloud/datastore PHP fails to register CursorValue in the binding as any text that I pass through will be recognised as string value, temp solution for now is to override the client library to implement custom logic to use cursor.

Comment: Depending on how deep your integration is, I believe cursors work with PHP-GDS (disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 0):

The cursor support is implemented since version 0.96, I'm using right now and it runs normally.